# How do I make a drag and drop to cart feature?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, drag-and-drop

I would like to add a drag and drop to cart feature to my music store with jQuery and AJAX, what methods should I use?
I would like the cart to update on the top menu, at the moment it just says `Cart (0)`. I would like it to update the link without the page refreshing or opening the cart page.
How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) is what you are looking for. To fill your cart, you'll have to perfrom [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request and process it output.

Something like

```
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $.ajax({
                            /* other params here*/
                                success:function(){
                                    /* process it here*/
                                }
                            })
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

A combination of jQueryUI [draggble](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) with a bit of simple [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to update the cart on the server and return a new view containing the updated total should work pretty well.